# Python でのドメイン情報取得に失敗する場合がある

Tags: python, python3

やりたいこと：
下記のコードでドメインの情報を取得しておりますが、
特定のドメイン (例: yahoo.co.jp) ではoutputのように取得出来ないです。

他の方法で取得する方法ありますでしょうか。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

---

コード

```
import whois
w = whois.whois('https://www.yahoo.co.jp/')
print(w)
```

output

```
{
  "domain_name": null,
  "registrant_org": "Yahoo Japan Corporation",
  "creation_date": null,
  "name_servers": null,
  "updated_date": null,
  "status": null
}
```

取得したい項目

```
{
  "domain_name": 
  "registrar": 
  "whois_server": 
  "referral_url": 
  "updated_date": 
  "expiration_date": 
  "name_servers": 
  "status": 
  "emails": 
  "dnssec": 
  "name":
  "org":,
  "address":
  "city":
  "state":
  "zipcode":
  "country":
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPドメイン名の登録管理業務とDNSを運用しているのは[株式会社日本レジストリサービス(JPRS)](https://jprs.jp/)で、質問にある `yahoo.co.jp` ドメインに関する whois 情報は以下の様になります。

```sh
$ whois -h whois.jprs.jp yahoo.co.jp
Domain Information: [ドメイン情報]
a. [ドメイン名]                 YAHOO.CO.JP
e. [そしきめい]                 やふーかぶしきがいしゃ
f. [組織名]                     ヤフー株式会社
g. [Organization]               Yahoo Japan Corporation
k. [組織種別]                   株式会社
l. [Organization Type]          Corporation
m. [登録担当者]                 HT46858JP
n. [技術連絡担当者]             KM56800JP
p. [ネームサーバ]               ns01.yahoo.co.jp
p. [ネームサーバ]               ns02.yahoo.co.jp
p. [ネームサーバ]               ns11.yahoo.co.jp
p. [ネームサーバ]               ns12.yahoo.co.jp
s. [署名鍵]                     
[状態]                          Connected (2021/09/30)
[登録年月日]                    2019/09/27
[接続年月日]                    2019/09/27
[最終更新]                      2020/10/01 01:02:24 (JST)
```

gTLD によって whois 情報の公開範囲が異なっていて、`.jp` ドメインの場合は [.JP 公開・開示対象情報一覧](https://jprs.jp/doc/rule/disclose-list.html) に記載されています。書かれてある通りに、オンライン公開されているのは上記の情報で、それ以外の情報は「情報開示請求手続き」を行う必要があります。

本題の [python-whois](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/) に関してですが、既に `.jp` ドメイン用のパーサが用意されています。

[whois/whois/parser.py](https://github.com/richardpenman/whois/blob/master/whois/parser.py#L853)

```py
class WhoisJp(WhoisEntry):
    """Whois parser for .jp domains
    """
    regex = {
        'domain_name': 'a\. \[Domain Name\]\s*(.+)',
        'registrant_org': 'g\. \[Organization\](.+)',
        'creation_date': r'\[Registered Date\]\s*(.+)',
        'name_servers': 'p\. \[Name Server\]\s*(.+)',  # list of name servers
        'updated_date':  '\[Last Update\]\s?(.+)',
        'status': '\[State\]\s*(.+)',  # list of statuses
    }

    def __init__(self, domain, text):
        if 'No match!!' in text:
            raise PywhoisError(text)
        else:
            WhoisEntry.__init__(self, domain, text, self.regex)
```

whois 情報が英語で表記されている事を前提としていますので、`g. [Organization]` のみを抽出しています。ところで、JPRS の whois サーバではドメイン名の末尾に `/e` を付けると whois 情報を英語表記で返してくれます。

```sh
$ whois -h whois.jprs.jp yahoo.co.jp/e
Domain Information:
a. [Domain Name]                YAHOO.CO.JP
g. [Organization]               Yahoo Japan Corporation
l. [Organization Type]          Corporation
m. [Administrative Contact]     HT46858JP
n. [Technical Contact]          KM56800JP
p. [Name Server]                ns01.yahoo.co.jp
p. [Name Server]                ns02.yahoo.co.jp
p. [Name Server]                ns11.yahoo.co.jp
p. [Name Server]                ns12.yahoo.co.jp
s. [Signing Key]                
[State]                         Connected (2021/09/30)
[Registered Date]               2019/09/27
[Connected Date]                2019/09/27
[Last Update]                   2020/10/01 01:02:24 (JST)
```

こちらを使います。

```py
import whois

query = 'yahoo.co.jp'
result = whois.NICClient().whois_lookup({
  'whoishost': 'whois.jprs.jp'
}, query + '/e', 0)

print(whois.parser.WhoisJp(query, result))
```

##### 実行結果

```js
{
  "domain_name": "YAHOO.CO.JP",
  "registrant_org": "Yahoo Japan Corporation",
  "creation_date": "2019-09-27 00:00:00",
  "name_servers": [
    "ns01.yahoo.co.jp",
    "ns02.yahoo.co.jp",
    "ns11.yahoo.co.jp",
    "ns12.yahoo.co.jp"
  ],
  "updated_date": "2020/10/01 01:02:24 (JST)",
  "status": "Connected (2021/09/30)"
}
```

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。上記の内容で取得出来ました。因みにですが`creation_date`で新規登録済みドメインを検索することできますでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、、、現状ではドメイン名での検索しかできないので無理でしょうね。。。